# Slab Foundation with Cracks and Uplift in Floors, Driveways and Back Patio

Tags: foundation, structural, crack, slab, inspection

I am buying house for the first time and the home inspection report came back saying there may be potential foundation issues. I have attached screenshots from the report below. This is an 1976, one story house at 78745, Austin, TX. I am wondering how serious the problem is and if I should move forward with the house. Many thanks in advance for your input!

Excerpt from the report

> Foundations 1. At the time of inspection the foundation appeared to
> have some movement considered beyond normal, exceeding acceptable
> tolerances. Observations made to support this opinion are listed, but
> not limited to the following: significant cracks observed on the
> exterior of the foundation; noticeable changes in the floor elevation;
> step cracks in the exterior veneer wall(s); interior sheetrock cracks
> and/or stress indicators; Typical settlement cracks Spalling or
> flaking occurring. A professional engineer should be consulted to
> evaluate the current integrity of the foundation and propose necessary
> repairs (if any).
>
> Cracked tile(s) were observed in the primary bedroom, hall, and living
> room. The crack appears to be following a pattern consistent with
> typical foundation settlement. Repair as needed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have a very good inspector. Run, don't look back. The foundation defects are caused by the ground, which could be mainly consisted of "expansive clay" that is very difficult to deal with.

Comment: Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry , I would not buy it; you may not have the option as most mortgage companies would not write a mortgage on a cracked foundation. The separation of the interior floor tiles are a bad sign for me. That is; the cracks in the brickwork (mortar) may not be serious, but the separated floor tile reflect a cracks in the pad/foundation which is a problem. My son had a house in Round Rock , after several years it showed cracks in the edge of foundation which ran into the brick. Then separation of interior floor tiles.  Bottom line, he rented it when he moved because no buyer could not get a mortgage.  He had a happy ending, found a cash buyer and took a reduced price. You may be able to find a tolerant mortgage company today, but what about in the future if you want to sell ?

Comment: Thank you for your input!